# C# trying to convert json list of strings to string[]

Tags: c#, json

**EDIT: wanted to delete this question but I am not allowed to.** As I copy pasted the valid json from some unity editor window, into the C# file to debug it, it got formatted in a odd way, why the json in my question looks wrong, and would never be able to translated into a string[]... In the editor the json string was correct `"[\"none\"]"`, which is why I didn't even notice it got corrupted when copy pasted... Not even when I pasted the code into stackoverflow. The second someone pointed out that it looked wrong I was aware of what was causing the issue. you can stop devoting now I get the point - I am not allowed to delete the question.

**Original question:**

I'm trying to convert a JSON string into a C# Sting[]

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private string[] list;
list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>("\"[(\"none(\"](\"");
Debug.Log(list);
```

But fails due to error:

> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.String[].
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable
>   (System.Object value, System.Type initialType, System.Type targetType)
>   (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)

I have also tried

```
private List<string> list;
list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>("\"[(\"none(\"](\"");
```

Fails due to error

> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable
>   (System.Object value, System.Type initialType, System.Type targetType)
>   (at <97722d3abc9f4cf69f9e21e6770081b3>:0)

Do I need another function, or does it have to do with my data type being wrong?

*OBS: I'm scripting within unity, so I'm not sure if I have all "normal" C# libs/stuff available. The Newtonsoft package is from the unity asset store.*

Comment: But your json doesn't look correct

Comment: You cant deserialize JSON when there **isn't any JSON**

Comment: `"[\"none\"]"` would make sense... as @PavelAnikhouski said your JSON is just one string value... Please [edit] post to clarify what you expect to happen with that "JSON" and *why*.

Comment: list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>("\"[(\"none\"]\""); whats with your brackets ( ( ) )

Comment: @maccettura string value is perfectly valid JSON - https://www.json.org/json-en.html (granted, string value is not an array of strings as OP wants, but it is still valid JSON)

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out. Didn't notice. it was copy pasted and got corrupted on the way...  But that Explains everything. Closing this question to not cause confusion for anyone else landing here

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I put the OP's json in a linter and as far as my eyes, or the linter is concerned it wasn't valid...

Comment: @maccettura sorry, you are right - I incorrectly un-escaped quotes in my head (only trust Fiddler :) )... Indeed `"[("none("]("` is not "string value" nor valid JSON - just some strange combination of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Json string is malformed.

```
        var jsonString = "[\"none\"]";
        var deserializedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonString);
        var backToJsonString = JsonSerializer.ToJsonString(deserializedList, StandardResolver.Default);
```